# #Value Error in a vba function to return a recordset

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I wrote the below vba function aiming to return a SQL record set into a cell. I get #Value error when I use this function. It should get two arguments, namely two cells, and simply return Yes or No. I checked the SQL query and it works fine when written as a subroutine. So pardon for replacing some sql commands with *

```
Public Function TrRe(No1 As String, No2 As String) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SourceText As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=****;Database=*****;Integrated Security=SSPI"
cn.Open
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
SourceText = " SELECT  " & _
            "   CASE  " & _
            "   WHEN ***** LIKE 'TEST%' OR *****=1 THEN 'Yes' " & _
            "   ELSE 'No " & _
            "   END " & _
            "  FROM *** "
            " WHERE ****=" & No1 & _
            "   AND ****=" & No2  
rs.ActiveConnection = cn
rs.Source = SourceText
rs.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
rs.LockType = adLockReadOnly
rs.Open
Set TrRe= rs
rs.Close
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Function
```

I would appreciate your comments/helps.

Update: a) The query always returns a 1x1 recordset and this is Yes or No.
b) The code should be written as a Function since I want to let the user to choose the inputs.

Comment: You can't return a recordset to a cell using a function in a cell.

Comment: @Rory Why not? What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS @Rory stated, you can't write a recordset into a cell. A `RecordSet` is an object, containing all kind of information, eg the field names and -types, the state, the connection, somehow the information about the current row that was read and so on. You can't (and you don't want to) write all that into a cell.

Your sql statement will return one row with exactly one field (containing either the string `yes` or `no`). In that case, you can simply write (note that this statement is without `Set`)

```
TrRe = rs(0)
```

That is a shortcut, fetching the first field of the *current* row. *Current* row is the first row, assuming that the sql statement was executed successfully and returns at least one row. To move to the next row, you would use `rs.MoveNext`. To check if there are any more rows, use `If rs.EOF Then`.

If you issue an sql that returns more than that, there are two handy commands:

(1) To write the complete data that was returned into Excel, use `Range.CopyFromRecordset`

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

(2) To read all data into a 2-dimensional array use `RecordSet.GetRows`

```
Dim data as Variant
data = rs.GetRows
dim row as long, col as long
For row = 0 To UBound(data, 2)  ' Index for rows = 2
    For col = 0 to UBound(data, 1) ' Index for fields (columns) = 1
        ... (do your stuff here)
    next col
Next row
```

Comment: I still get the same error message. How come then that a recordset can be returned to a cell by through a macro but the same process fails when putting it to a function?

Comment: A function and a sub (I assume this is what you call a "macro") are the same except that a) a function returns a value and b) you can, with some limitation, use a function directly in a cell (this is called an UDF) - if it returns a simple value (number, date, string). You cannot "return a recordset to a cell", neither in a sub nor in a function. You can (as shown in my code), put a field of the resultset into a cell.